# Logical quest - get TableCell from one dimensional index

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Thats not a language specific question, but i need it for a java game. 
I have a table (2d array) with the dimension 3x3.
So the one dimensional Indexes of the cells are:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

When have this index, i want to get the 2d index from this - so input 5 return 2,2 , input 8 returns  3,2.

My Mind isnt able to find a way to do this :/ I thought about modulo.. but how can i use it here?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use two array list , one for the index of this value for each entry and one for the value in each index .

Comment: or ceate class and use it to store object of the value and index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Row:** (index - 1) ***div*** nrOfColumns + 1

**Column:** (index - 1) ***mod*** nrOfColumns + 1

Your examples :

- (5-1) div 3 + 1 = 2, (5-1) mod 3 + 1 = 2 --> (2, 2)

  (8-1) div 3 + 1 = 3, (8-1) mod 3 + 1 = 2 --> (3, 2)

Comment: WOW Perfect! Thats what i was searching for :))
Thank you!